# Unity cannot find package namespace for the digital human package

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm toying around with the [Demoteam digital human package](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.demoteam.digital-human). I need to adress the [SkinAttachment component](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.demoteam.digital-human/blob/master/Runtime/SkinAttachment.cs). but it seems Unity has no knowledge of the necessary namespace `Unity.DemoTeam.DigitalHuman`. When i'm adding `using Unity.DemoTeam.DigitalHuman`, i get this error:

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Demoteam' does not exist in the namespace 'Unity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

What am i doing wrong? The component exists and functions properly in my scene, so it definately loaded correctly, i just don't know how to adress it via scripting.

Comment: It says the error is Demoteam not DemoTeam as you suggested. Perhaps thats why

Comment: It *should* be DemoTeam (capital T), the link to the SkinAttachment source file has the namespace spelled like that. Nevertheless, neither Demoteam nor DemoTeam is found.

Comment: Well. did you install it using package  manager or git? If git. That could be why

Comment: I used the git adress to add it in the package manager. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: No. Then look at their sample. See what's different.

Comment: Their sample never adresses the component by script :(

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a upperrcase T, because it looks like that's what the package is using. I'm new to development, but trust me, Unity is SUPER picky about capitals.

(edit: I just realized BugFinder had the same idea as me, I'm not trying to copy them :) )